# Can't able to focus on newly added text field flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Demo {
  int no;
  String value;
  Demo({this.value, this.no});
}

class Control {
  TextEditingController controller;
  FocusNode node;
  Control({this.controller, this.node});
}

class DemoPage extends StatefulWidget {
  static const routeName = '/Demo';
  DemoPage({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _DemoPageState createState() => _DemoPageState();
}

class _DemoPageState extends State<DemoPage> {
  List<Demo> txtfield;
  List<Control> control;

  @override
  void initState() {
    txtfield = [];
    control = [];
    // no = 0;
    add();
    super.initState();
  }

  int no;
  void add() {
    no = (no ?? 0) + 1;
    setState(() {});
    txtfield.add(Demo(no: no));
    control.add(Control(
      controller: TextEditingController(),
      node: FocusNode(),
    ));
    // no = no +1;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // print(txtfield[0].no);
    // FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(control[control.length - 1].node);
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: Center(
        child: Card(
          child: Container(
            child: Column(
              children: txtfield
                  .map((f) => TextField(
                        controller: control[f.no - 1].controller,
                        focusNode: control[f.no - 1].node,
                        autofocus: true,
                      ))
                  .toList(),
            ),
            width: 400,
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
          ),
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
        onPressed: () {
          add();
          print(no);
          FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(control[control.length - 1].node);
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I used above code. but I can't able to focus on a newly added text field.
when I check for that newly added text field has focus, it shows true, but I can't able to write anything in that text field.

I don't know what is an error in that code.
I search for this solution for more than 4 days. but I can't able to find solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the `onPressed` of your floatingActionButton change this line:

`FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(control[control.length - 1].node);`

with this

`control[control.length - 1].node.requestFocus();`

Comment: Thank you very much, I'm searching a lot to find this solution

Comment: It's alright! You can accept my answer clicking the check-mark, if helped you to solve the problem.